# Can't center page using flexbox with styled components

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I'm struggling to center my page using flexbox with styled components in a Next.js app. Any ideas?

This is my Blog Component

```js
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown'
import BlogPostStyles from './styles/BlogPostStyles';

const BlogComponent = ({ data: { post: { fields: { title, body } } } }) => {
    return (
        <BlogPostStyles>
            <article>
                <ReactMarkdown>{body}</ReactMarkdown>
            </article>
        </BlogPostStyles>
    );
};

export default BlogComponent;
```

This is my BlogStyles Component

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';
    
const BlogPostStyles = styled.div`
    max-width: 1200px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
`;
    
export default BlogPostStyles;
```

Comment: Did you actually setup Styled Components? Please take a look at the official documentation: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-styled-components
Server-side render setup is in particular a complex, the example will demo that.

Answer (score 0):

add `align-items:center`

try add `width:100%`

try add `height:100vh`

to `BlogPostStyles`

this is more css bug, not next.js :)